# Extract entity strings from an Outlook item using VSTO (Outlook client not O365 based Office Add-ins)

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin

With web based Office add-ins, outlook provides APIs to extract entity strings (Address, contacts, email address etc.) from an Outlook item subject, body fields.

Please refer below articles.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/extract-entity-strings-from-an-item

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/match-strings-in-an-item-as-well-known-entities

**Is there any similar thing available for COM based outlook plugins (VSTO) ?**
If not in built with Outlook API then any Microsoft service which we can use to pass text and get such results can also help.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Did you find a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve outlook email item by using VSTO.
Here is the test code below:

```
private void InternalStartup()
    {

        var inbox = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        var mailItem = inbox.Items[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
        var subject = mailItem.Subject;
        var body = mailItem.Body;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Subject = {0}, Body = {1}", subject,body));
    }
```

You can have a look this MSDN document below for MailItem members
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members.aspx

For your additional question, you can use [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications) (Exchange Web Server) to retrieve your email item.

Comment: This question is not about accessing email item. It's about extract entity strings out of subject, body text. Most of these entities rely on natural language recognition. Please refer link I have provided in my question.